# Изменении свойств одного блока при наведении на другой

Tags: css

Есть два блока `div`. Как при наведении на один из них, другой перевести из `opacity: 0` в `opacity: 1`?

```
.div1 {
  opacity:0;
}
.div2:hover .div1 {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Пробовал так, но не работает почему-то.

Comment: Всё зависит от того, как div1 и div2 расположены относительно друг друга

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.div1 {
  opacity:0;
}
.div2:hover + .div1{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class='div2'>Наведи</div>
<div class='div1'>Я тут</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.div1 {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left:10px;
}

.div2:hover > .div1 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='div2'>Вложенный вариант
  <div class='div1'>А вот и я ...</div>
</div>
```